# Python - Convert currency code to its sign

Tags: python, currency

In Python, how can I convert currency code to its sign?

For example, `USD` would be converted to `$`, and `JPY` would be converted to `¥`.

If there isn't a generic way to do this, is there any simple dictionary of these on the Web?

Thanks.

Comment: Input would be the currency code - USD, JPY, etc.

Comment: Note that many currencies have no symbol as such. "Kr" for example is not a symbol, it's just an abbreviation for "Krona" used in Scandinavian currencies. Actually writing out the currency "SEK", "NOK" "ISK" etc would in most cases be preferable for these. Also note that many symbols are not unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a package that maintains a list all currencies with symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248694/is-there-a-package-that-maintains-a-list-all-currencies-with-symbols)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the [locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#module-locale) module:

```
import locale

locales=('en_AU.utf8', 'en_BW.utf8', 'en_CA.utf8',
    'en_DK.utf8', 'en_GB.utf8', 'en_HK.utf8', 'en_IE.utf8', 'en_IN', 'en_NG',
    'en_PH.utf8', 'en_US.utf8', 'en_ZA.utf8',
    'en_ZW.utf8', 'ja_JP.utf8')
for l in locales:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, l)
    conv=locale.localeconv()
    print('{ics} ==> {s}'.format(ics=conv['int_curr_symbol'],
                                 s=conv['currency_symbol']))
```

yields:

```
AUD  ==> $
BWP  ==> Pu
CAD  ==> $
DKK  ==> kr
GBP  ==> £
HKD  ==> HK$
EUR  ==> €
INR  ==> ₨
NGN  ==> ₦
PHP  ==> Php
USD  ==> $
ZAR  ==> R
ZWD  ==> Z$
JPY  ==> ￥
```

Note you need the locale information installed on your machine. On Ubuntu, this means having the right `language-pack-*` packages installed.

On *nix systems, you can find the list of known locales (e.g. `en_GB.utf8`) with

```
locale -a
```

I don't know of a way to obtain this list from within Python (without using `subprocess`).

Comment: This doesn't do any conversion, it just prints out a mapping for a fixed set of locales.

Answer (score 18):

How about [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/)?

```
from babel import numbers
print numbers.get_currency_symbol('USD', locale='en') # => $1,500.00
print numbers.get_currency_symbol('GBP', locale='fr_FR') # => 1 500,00 £UK
```

Comment: This formats a number as a currency. To convert a currency code to a symbol you can use babel's `get_currency_symbol` function.

Comment: If you want to specify decimal places, pass `format=` and `currency_digits=` arguments. For example, to round to the nearest whole number: : `numbers.format_currency(1, 'USD', locale='en', format='#,##0.#', currency_digits=False)` is `'1'`. To enable extra decimal places:  `numbers.format_currency(1.2345, 'USD', locale='en', format='#,##0.00######', currency_digits=False)` is `'1.2345'`

Answer (score 7):

[Forex-python](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python) package will convert Currency code to its sign.

```
>>> from forex_python.converter import CurrencyCodes
>>> c = CurrencyCodes()
>>> print c.get_symbol('GBP')
£
```

And you can convert amount from one currency to other.

```
>>> c= CurrencyRates()
>>> c.convert('USD', 'INR', 10)
674.73
```

give it a try

Comment: This converts `USD` -> `US$`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `dict`.

```
>>> currencies = {'USD': '$', 'AUD': '$', 'EUR': '€'}
>>> print currencies['USD']
$
>>> print currencies['AUD']
$
>>> print currencies['EUR']
€
>>> print currencies['GBP']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'GBP'
```

Answer (score 4):

Does [this](http://www.xe.com/symbols.php) help?

> This page is a list of symbols used in
>   everyday life to denote that a number
>   is a monetary value, such as the
>   dollar sign "$", the Pound sign "£",
>   and the Euro sign "€".
>
> IMPORTANT - We also maintain a full
>   list of three-letter codes used
>   internationally to distinguish one
>   currency from another, such as "USD"
>   for the United States Dollar, "GBP"
>   for the United Kingdom Pound, and
>   "EUR" for the Euro. To see a complete
>   list of all of these codes, refer to
>   our [XE.com - ISO 4217 Type Currency
>   Code List](http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php).

You should be able to create a useful dict mapping 3-letter codes to the appropriate Unicode currency symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to use babel [get_currency_symbol](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html?highlight=get_currency_symbol#babel.numbers.get_currency_symbol) function.

```
from babel.numbers import get_currency_symbol
get_currency_symbol('USD', locale='en_US')
```