# Is there a package that maintains a list all currencies with symbols?

Tags: python, localization, currency

Is there a python package that provides list of all (or fairly complete) currencies **with the symbols**  (like "$" for USD).

There are excellent pycountry, [py-moneyed](https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed) and [ccy](http://code.google.com/p/ccy/) but these do not have symbols.

Comment: By "symbols", do you mean the conventional abbreviations (like "$" for USD)?

Comment: Yes. Will update the question again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a lot more than you really need, but [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) does include currencies, in the Locale currency_symbols dictionary.  Some may require a little parsing, though; for example, USD is 'US$' rather than just the dollar sign, while others, like the Euro or Yuan, have no such prefix.

I believe Babel uses the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) as its source.

Comment: I think the older Babel has been stalled and there is an update. Any help on if the new library still supports currency codes and symbols? I checked their website, couldn't find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
import locale

locales=('en_AG', 'en_AU.utf8', 'en_BW.utf8', 'en_CA.utf8',
    'en_DK.utf8', 'en_GB.utf8', 'en_HK.utf8', 'en_IE.utf8', 'en_IN', 'en_NG',
    'en_NZ.utf8', 'en_PH.utf8', 'en_SG.utf8', 'en_US.utf8', 'en_ZA.utf8',
    'en_ZW.utf8', 'ja_JP.utf8')
for l in locales:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, l)
    conv=locale.localeconv()
    print('{int_curr_symbol} ==> {currency_symbol}'.format(**conv))
    # XCD  ==> $
    # AUD  ==> $
    # BWP  ==> Pu
    # CAD  ==> $
    # DKK  ==> kr
    # GBP  ==> £
    # HKD  ==> HK$
    # EUR  ==> €
    # INR  ==> ₨
    # NGN  ==> ₦
    # NZD  ==> $
    # PHP  ==> Php
    # SGD  ==> $
    # USD  ==> $
    # ZAR  ==> R
    # ZWD  ==> Z$
    # JPY  ==> ￥
```

This depends on what locales are installed on your machine. On *nix machines, you can find out what locales are available with the command `locale -a`.

Comment: @ubuntu I am aware of this but I am looking for a package that has an exclusive list of symbols. Can not rely of locale(s) installed on machine in this case.

Comment: @ubuntu, I'm using Mac Yosemite and iPython Notebook. I'm not able to set locale to any other values. It just gives me this error,  `Error: unsupported locale setting`

Answer (score 7):

I created [Forex-python](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python) package which maintains all latest Currency code and its sign.

```
>>> from forex_python.converter import CurrencyCodes
>>> c = CurrencyCodes()
>>> print c.get_symbol('GBP')
£
```

And you can convert amount from one currency to other.

```
>>> from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
>>> c = CurrencyRates()
>>> c.convert('USD', 'INR', 10)
674.73
```