# Get currency symbol in PHP

Tags: php, formatting, currency

Let's start with simple piece of code to format money with `NumberFormatter`:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(123456789, 'JPY');
```

This prints: `¥123,456,789`.

This is ok if you want to format money.

But what I want to do is to get currency symbol (e.g. ¥) for given currency ISO 4217 code (e.g. JPY).

My first guess was to try using:

```
$formatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
```

But that gives currency symbol for locale given in constructor (en_US), $ in my case.

Is there a way to get currency symbol by currency ISO 4217 code in PHP?

Comment: The problem is that the currency symbol can appear either before or after the number. What are you using the symbol for?

Comment: Just do a regex for anything thats not a digit or a comma. Something like `/[^0-9,]*/`.

Comment: Some of the symbols will be multi-byte so a simple string search won't work very well.

Comment: I want to avoid regex. Actually, I wanted to fix https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/MoneyType.php#L106 and get rid of this regex, I thought PHP supports this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The most useful related resource I have found is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483158/python-convert-currency-code-to-its-sign) (yes, it's python, but all those functions are available in PHP), which is a bit of a nasty "solution". The root of the problem is that this functionality is dependent on the host OS having the appropriate locale information available - but at the same time I don't see a reason for this not to be possible within those restrictions.

Comment: @DaveRandom I tried and `currency_symbol` and most of other data is empty for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: Warning: `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` has been [deprecated since PHP 8.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration83.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I achieved this using https://github.com/symfony/Intl:

```
Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('EUR')
```

returns

```
'€'.
```

**Symfony version > 4.3**

It's worth pointing out for SF4.3 and above this has been deprecated:

```
/**
 * Returns the bundle containing currency information.
 *
 * @return CurrencyBundleInterface The currency resource bundle
 *
 * @deprecated since Symfony 4.3, to be removed in 5.0. Use {@see Currencies} instead.
 */
public static function getCurrencyBundle(): CurrencyBundleInterface
{
```

So, instead you can do:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Currencies;
echo Currencies::getSymbol('AUD');
```

Comment: Technically (IMHO) this doesn't actually answer the question, which was about PHP, not Symfony.

Comment: @geoidesic I asked this question, and the goal is to get currency symbol in PHP. Using third party libraries is allowed and encouraged.

Comment: Also, what a beautiful syntax.

Comment: See Federico Nicolas Motta's answer.

Answer (score 61):

First of all, there is no international global currency symbol table, that anyone on the planet could read and understand.

In each region/country the currency symbols will differ, that`s why you must determine them based on who is reading, using the browser / user locale.

The correct way is as you guessed, using NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, but you first have to set the appropriate locale like **en-US@currency=JPY**:

```
$locale='en-US'; //browser or user locale
$currency='JPY';
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( $locale."@currency=$currency", NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$symbol = $fmt->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;");
echo $symbol;
```

This way the symbol will be understandable by the user.

For example, $symbol will be:

- *Canadian dollar* (CAD) : **CA$** in USA, **CAD** in Romania , **$CA** in Iran
- *Iran Rial* (IRR): **IRR** in USA, while in Iran will be **﷼**

Comment: Excellent!! +1. I just wish there was a way to retrieve `locale` based on currency `iso`. Something like `rlocaleconv(int_curr_symbol, 'JPY')` or so!

Answer (score 5):

Since the symbols can be multi-byte I used mb_*() functions to correctly grab the all non-punctuation and non-digit chars which would just leaves the symbol.

```
function get_currency_symbol($string)
{
    $symbol = '';
    $length = mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $char = mb_substr($string, $i, 1, 'utf-8');
        if (!ctype_digit($char) && !ctype_punct($char))
            $symbol .= $char;
    }
    return $symbol;
}

$format = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$string = $format->formatCurrency(123456789, 'JPY');
echo get_currency_symbol($string);
```

Comment: Currency symbols may be more than one character, e.g., Estonia Kroon = "kr".

Comment: Currency symbol is not always one char http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign. Thanks.

Comment: @umpirsky please see updated code which supports multi-char symbols.

Comment: Yes, but it's hacky, similar to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/MoneyType.php#L106 I will accept it if I find no other solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you set the locale using this function `setlocale("LC_ALL", "es_AR");`
You can use `localeconv()['currency_symbol']` or `localeconv()['int_curr_symbol']` to get the locale currency symbol and the international variation of the currency symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Symfony Intl** Component

Install it via composer using  `composer require symfony/intl`

Then get the HTML symbol with the following

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Currencies;
\Locale::setDefault('en');
$symbol = Currencies::getSymbol('INR'); // => '₹'
echo $symbol;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code and this code in php

```
$CS = new NumberFormatter('en_PH', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$CS = $CS->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
```

I got a currency symbol of Philippine Peso ₱₱₱₱

I also tried HTML code '&#8369' for Philippine Peso ₱. But it does not working when using in php server php mail specially if you are using an email server.

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptic has a good answer, but there is a simpler way to do it:

```
preg_replace('#[a-z0-9.]*#i', '', $formatter->formatCurrency('0', $currency))
```

This is a nice simple inline solution that doesn't require declaring another function, however it also doesn't properly handle all cases - i.e. currencies where letters are part of the output. But for distinguishing between e.g. $ and £, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('CurrencySymbol')
```

Will give you an associative array of 3 letter currency codes to their symbol.

Can then use like this:

```
$curArr = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('CurrencySymbol');
echo $curArr['GBP'];
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this variant:

```
$formatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::INTL_CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
```