# Displaying currency symbol in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, currency

How can I display the currency symbol in twig? I saved the numeric value of the symbol like:

```
for EURO : &#8364;
for DOLLAR: &#36;
```

When I render these values, `&` is converted to `&amp;` and the currency symbol does not show. Any idea will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using the utf8 characters instead of the html entities?

Comment: Yes. I've actually considered that. Its just that I've found this easier. Thank you so much for the idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it well, you've to add a [function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id2) or a [filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id3) which is called as a helper to render currency symbols within your twig templates.

To use the following function,

```
{{ currency('en_US') }}
```

You've to add a [twig extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) as follow,

```
xxx.twig.your_extension:
    class: XXX\YourBundle\Twig\YourExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

You've then to add a `currency` function,

```
namespace XXX\YourBundle\Twig;

class YourExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            'currency' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'currencyFunction'),
        );
    }

    public function currencyFunction($locale) {
        $formatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
        $symbol = $formatter->getSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);

        return $symbol;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'your_extension';
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I am a little bit confused. What locale should I use for euro symbol?

Comment: You should then use those related to euro countries (fr-FR / it-IT / ...)

Comment: For referencing purposes, also you can find the answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16942190/1794894

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. When rendering, I need to use the [**raw**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter of twig.

Comment: Yes, by using raw filter your variable is not escaped. Btw, I added a much cleaner solution that allows you render any currency symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old thread, but for the new people coming here, Twig has now an extension for the currency symbols (with new filters |currency_symbol ) as you can see in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/currency_symbol.html)