# Twig doesn't render dollar ($) sign

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Product title is **"Navy Maverick Aviator Jacket $10"**

But when I try to render it with twig `{{ product.title }}` I get **"Navy Maverick Aviator Jacket"**

Comment: This is not a twig issue if the string is within `product.title` - must not be in that variable at all.

Comment: Does it show up if you do `{{ product.title|raw }}`?

Comment: {{ product.title|raw }} this doesn't work.

Comment: @fire This is twig issue because when I var_dump variable I can see everything is ok.

Comment: @BeatAlex it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: what is the output of {{ dump(product.title) }} ?

Comment: Output is '1Navy Maverick Aviator Jacket '

Comment: But when I var_dump variable before sending it to layout I see value is private '_title' => string '1Navy Maverick Aviator Jacket $10'

Comment: do you have a getter/access method for the variable title that does any kind of modification to the value?

Comment: he must have, there is no way its a Twig issue

Comment: save the numeric value of the symbol (&#36;) and then render it using {{ product.title | raw }}

Comment: http://twigfiddle.com/npi2eq

Comment: From your var_dump, it looks like `product` is some sort of object. `_title` is a private property inside of this object and there's an abstraction layer between this internal private property and your getter function. Examine the class of this object for the `getTitle` method and paste it in your question. Without these details, your problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should create a twig extension to show the dollar symbol as explained in this post [Displaying currency symbol in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172222/displaying-currency-symbol-in-twig)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `{{ product.title | raw }}` It will render the raw value without escaping

Comment: Are you sure the `product.title` contains `$10` maybe you have an other column `product.price`