# How to get the currency symbol by currency code from the PHP Intl ( ICU library )

Tags: php, currency, numberformatter

In PHP I know currency codes (EUR, GBP, USD...), but I do not know locale.
I need to get a currency symbol for them

```
GBP -> £
EUR -> €
USD -> $
```

Using

```
$obj = new \NumberFormatter( null, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $obj->formatCurrency( null, 'EUR');
```

I can get € 0.00, so the NumberFormatter library can convert currency code to currency symbol.
But how to get currency symbol only?

```
$obj = new \NumberFormatter( null, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$obj->setTextAttribute ( \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, 'EUR');
echo $obj->getSymbol ( \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
```

Also do not do the translation and returns $ always.

Comment: if you want a propel solution, you need the local! [Check this answer: Get currency symbol in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30026774/5356216)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get currency symbol in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897516/get-currency-symbol-in-php)

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately this isn’t as easy as it should be, but here’s how to get the currency symbol by currency code, for a locale:

```php
function getCurrencySymbol($locale, $currency)
{
    // Create a NumberFormatter
    $formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

    // Prevent any extra spaces, etc. in formatted currency
    $formatter->setPattern('¤');

    // Prevent significant digits (e.g. cents) in formatted currency
    $formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS, 0);

    // Get the formatted price for '0'
    $formattedPrice = $formatter->formatCurrency(0, $currency);

    // Strip out the zero digit to get the currency symbol
    $zero = $formatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::ZERO_DIGIT_SYMBOL);
    $currencySymbol = str_replace($zero, '', $formattedPrice);

    return $currencySymbol;
}
```

Tested with locales: ar, cs, da, de, en, en_GB, en_US, es, fr, fr_CA, he, it, ja, ko, nb, nl, ru, sk, sv, zh

Tested with currencies: AUD, BRL, CAD, CNY, EUR, GBP, HKD, ILS, INR, JPY, KRW, MXN, NZD, THB, TWD, USD, VND, XAF, XCD, XOF, XPF

Comment: I think that the `$zero = $formatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::ZERO_DIGIT_SYMBOL);` isn't necessary and you can use `0` in the last operation `$currencySymbol = str_replace(0, '', $formattedPrice);`

Comment: There is a way simpler solution. [Get currency symbol in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30026774/5356216)

Comment: @ZoltánSüle way better! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this way works improperly for some cases (e.g. `getCurrencySymbol("cs", "CZK")`), leaving extra bytes after the string. I guess, it breaks UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly not the best solution but you could always do something like ...

```
$obj = new \NumberFormatter( 'en_us', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formattedValue = $obj->formatCurrency( 0, 'EUR');
$currencySymbol = trim(str_replace('0.00','',$formattedValue));
```

The important thing is using a locale and value where you know the expected output format (e.g. en_us and 0.00) and you can then pick the currency symbol out correctly.

Note: this might need some adjustment for certain currencies

Comment: This will fail with currencies in India since they use a different 0 (०) plus a few other countries using other symbols.