# Get currency symbol in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I would like to get the currency symbol for an ISO-3 string in Laravel 8.x.

Example:

```
$iso_code = 'EUR';
$symbol = convertToSymbolFunction('EUR');

echo $symbol;
```

...and the `$symbol` would equal to:

```
'€'
```

I know that there is a native PHP NumberFormatter function, but that requires the locale of the user. I'm wondering if there's a simpler version or a library for Laravel that supports something like the above example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get currency symbol in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897516/get-currency-symbol-in-php)

Comment: @Jeto Nope, I've read that, and I don't want to use PHP's Number formatter as written in my original post.

Comment: I know you've mentioned it. But the picked answer explains exactly why you don't really have a choice: there is no universal/"official" symbol for any given currency.

Comment: There is already an answer while using Symfony in the same thread, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942190/9992791 Your question is really vague, and Jeto already answered with a real solution.