# Determine if the string contains any currency sign?

Tags: python, string, currency

How can I find out if some string contains any currency sign? Say, I need a function that returns 1 if a string contains any currency sign(USD,GBP,RUR,etc)  and 0 - otherwise

```
321->0
$32->1
34$->1
```

Is there a way to do it easily in python?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483158/python-convert-currency-code-to-its-sign

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make your own function, e.g.:

```
def any_curr(s, curr="¥$€£"):
    return any(c in s for c in curr)
```

This returns `True` or `False`.

You can supply either a string of characters to check or an iterable of strings, e.g.

```
>>> any_curr("EUR250", ["USD", "GBP", "EUR"])
True
```